# Have sapply depend on column in same matrix

Tags: r, loops

I am in the process of replacing all loops with the much faster apply function. I have a problem making the function depend on the previous column.

Currently, I need to assign a grade based on exam score, which is possible using

```
data <- matrix(runif(100),20,5)
colnames(data) <- letters[1:5]
sapply(colnames(data),function(x){
  ifelse((data[,x] <= 0 & data[,x] < 0.50),'C',
         ifelse((data[,x] >= 0.50 & data[,x] < 0.70) ,'B','A'))})
```

However, is it possible to continue to use the apply function and extend the code so that regardless of the column where a 'C' is returned all subsequent grades to right of that column are replace with a 'C' in that row.

Thanks a million

R.

Comment: `apply` family commands aren't always faster.  Also, if you describe what you want better we may be able to help.  Please tell us your intent rather than just dumping some code which we have to parse through (which may or may may not actually be what you want!)

Comment: Sorry, I am aggregating grades for university students in my facility. I need to take numerical grades and convert them to letters , scores between 40-50 = D, 50-60 = C and so on. This is taken care of with the code above. For the continuous assessment part of course, if the student falls below a certain grade, the student will require a repeat - regardless of subsequent CA grades. I currently do this in a loop, which works but I thought it might be cleaner and quicker using the apply function. Thank you for your help, R.

Answer (score 2):

First of, you don't need any loop nor `ifelse` in your current code; just use `cut`:

```
as.character(cut(data,c(0,0.5,0.7,1),labels=c("C","B","A"),right=FALSE))->cdata
dim(data)->dim(cdata);cdata->data
```

You second problem (filling all cells after first "C" with "C"s) requires a loop and can be done like this:

```
t(apply(data,1,function(x)
 ifelse(seq(along=x)<min(c(which(x=="C"),Inf)),x,"C"))
)
```

Comment: Very nice use of `ifelse` to replace the Cs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using nested `ifelse` statements, try using `cut`. It makes things a bit easier to read. For example:

```
# Create data
data <- matrix(runif(100),20,5) 
# Assign a grade
x=apply(data, MARGIN=2, cut, breaks=c(0,0.5,0.7,1),labels=c('C','B','A'))
```

Now you make your repeating C function, which is a little tricky.

```
# Make the repeating C function.
find.c=function(x) 
    if ('C' %in% x) 
        c(
          x[seq(0,match('C',x)-1)], # Everything before the first C
          rep('C',length(x) - match('C',x) + 1) # After the first C
        )  
    else x
# Run it.
t(apply(x,MARGIN=1,find.c))
```

Comment: Nice use of `match` to avoid the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- matrix(runif(100),20,5)
colnames(data) <- letters[1:5]
data.let <- sapply(colnames(data),function(x){
  ifelse((data[,x] <= 0 | data[,x] < 0.50),'C',
         ifelse((data[,x] >= 0.50 & data[,x] < 0.70) ,'B','A'))})
# Note the change of & to | above to make your sample data work

apply( data.let, 1, replaceCs )
```

Where `replaceCs is a function that takes in a vector and replaces anything following a C with a C.

One such example:

```
replaceCs <- function(x) {
   for(i in seq(2,length(x))) {
      if(x[i-1]=="C") x[i] <- "C"
   }
   x
}
```

Probably something more clever could be concocted with `rollapply`.